# Using The New Google Vault CSV Metadata File To Correlate Metadata With Message In MBOX Export

Tags: google-workspace, google-vault-api

We're trying to line up the new CSV metadata file with emails within the MBOX file.  Back when it was in XML format, there was a field named 'mboxfromline' that we were able to use to line up the entries in the XML to the emails in the MBOX export.

With the new CSV metadata file, that field no longer exists.  Google states that the Rfc822MessageId field can be used to correlate metadata with the message in an MBOX export, but we have noticed that it is not a unique value and multiple email headers can have the same Rfc822MessageId.

Does anyone have any guidance or feedback?

Thanks!